R validate package - return rules that are violated for each row
I am attempting to utilize the R package Validate for our data QC process (we enter our data in the field, and small mistakes happen - as well as there being lots of old data that is quite messy). I have figured out how to write out rules using validator(), see how many items passed or failed using confront(), and see which entries violate the rules using violating(). What I need is a way to tell which rules are violated where.
# an example dataframe
plot <- 1:4
DBH <- c(1.1, 2, 0.7, 3.2)
df <- data.frame(plot, DBH)

# creating a rule - DBH must be greater than or equal to 1
rule <- validator(DBH >= 1)

# confronting the dataset with the rule
x <- confront(df, rule)
summary(x)

# show which rows of the dataframe do not comply with the rule
y <- violating(df, rule)
y

confront() tells me which rules were violated how many times, and violating() tells me which dataframe rows violated the rules. How do I merge the two so I can tell which rules were violated where?
Is there a way to add a column to the output of the violating() function that will tell the user which rule(s) was violated? I know I can add names and descriptions to my rules, but I need a way to merge that into the output of violating().
My actual dataset has 50+ variables and many more rules, so multiple rules could be violated for a single row of the dataframe.

You can use ref. This gives you a T/F matrix: each row for each id (unique row identifier in validated data) and each column represents a rule. For example, building on one of validate's examples: w <- women; w$id <- letters[1:nrow(w)]; v <- validator(weight == ref$weight, height == ref$height); values(confront(w, v, data.frame(height = '50', weight = '117'), key='id'))

This is a bit confusing to me... I understand basically what the code is doing, but I don't get why the rules get set within confront(). What is validator() doing if not setting the rules? Can I create and use 2 validator objects within confront() that establish reference data as well as the rules?
